# Why did you give me in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

A policeman has just given me a ticket, and he has not left yet.
Even if this is not really the past can I ask to him:

> Why did you give me this ticket?

He can reply " because you didn't pay the parking" and I reply "ok, I thought it was because ..."

I am wondering if "why did you give me this ticket" is correct instead of the present perfect version.

Comment: Which part do you think is incorrect? There are a few little mistakes, and we have no way of knowing which ones you're asking about. Please edit your question and indicate the one aspect of that sentence that you're unsure about. Please also tell us what you know about that aspect of English so we don't repeat things you things you already know.

Comment: In my country, 'fines' are only handed out by a judge in a court. What a policeman gives you, to pay at once or within a given time period, is called a 'fixed penalty notice', but most people call them 'tickets'. Other countries have what they call 'tickets'.

Comment: @gotube I hope this is better

Comment: @safarie I still don't know what aspect of English you're unsure about. Is it your choice of simple past rather than present perfect?

Comment: You say "a policeman has just given me a ticket" (implying that it has already happened) but then "the action is still in the present" (implying that it is still happening). Please resolve that discrepancy.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Yes, the last sentence was not appropriate

Comment: @gotube Yes, sorry, this is the difference between past simple and present perfect in the question.
Here, I would prefer simple past because the action "give a ticket " is past but I don't know if it's true

Answer (score 0):

No, the ticket is in the *past*; the policeman has **already** given the ticket (or left it on the windshield).

*Ah!* But a "moving violation" would be different, because the offender can ask the officer, "Why are you writing that ticket [right now]?"

Past can be 14 billion years ago (or 3.33... [kalpas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu_units_of_time#Current_kalpa), if you prefer), or [Planck time](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_time) ago, 10<sup>-44</sup> seconds, but it's still considered the past.

Comment: Therefore, the question tense is appropriate here, if the ticket is already on the windshield?

Answer (score 0):

Both *Why did you give me this ticket?* and *Why have you given me this ticket?* are both completely normal here.

In many situations, the choice between the two forms does not correspond to *any* difference in the objective circumstances, but only in how the speaker is choosing to think of them, or to refer to them.

*Why have you given me this ticket?* suggests that the speaker is thinking of the continuing process that begins with the ticket.

Comment: Thank you, I understand better, and the simple past just tell about the past action but on the present consequences?

Comment: Sort of. The simple past says that the speaker is choosing to refer to the event as completed. It says absolutely nothing about whether or not there are present consequences, just that the speaker is not choosing to focus on them, if they exist.